# php HttpRequestException when sending file in HttpRequest

Tags: php, httprequest

i'm trying to do HTTP POST and send file from local php script using [HttpRequest](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php) class.
the code for testupload.php is:

```
<?php
$r = new HttpRequest('http://127.0.0.1:5090/upload.php', HttpRequest::METH_POST);
$r->addPostFile('app', 'abc.txt');//if this line is commented the exception is gone
try {
    echo $r->send()->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
?>
```

i'm getting the following exception when:

```
exception 'HttpInvalidParamException' with message 'Empty or too short HTTP message: ''' in
D:\xampp\htdocs\testupload.php:0 inner exception 'HttpRequestException' with
message 'Failed to open/read local data from file/application; failed creating formpost 
data (http://127.0.0.1:5090/upload.php)' in D:\xampp\htdocs\testupload.php:8 
Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\testupload.php(0): HttpRequest->send() #1 {main}
```

the file abc.txt is located in the same directory. what is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late but try checking if you haven't accidentally deleted (unlinked) the file before calling "$r->send()->getBody();" (this was my experience). If you are not deleting the file, try adding the absolute path to the file and/or check file access permissions.